# RecyclerView scrollbar jumps back to top after first item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I created a very basic RecyclerView example.

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new TestAdapter());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }

    public static class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TestAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, viewGroup, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
            viewHolder.tv.setText("Row " + (i + 1));
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 30;
        }

        public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            TextView tv;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                tv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I scroll beyond the first item, the scrollbar jumps back to the top and then continues normally. The second problem is when I scroll to the bottom, the scrollbar stops to early. Is this a bug in the support lib or my own fault?

Comment: It seems to be a bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=scrollbar&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=78545

Comment: Try to use v7 recyclerview library https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7  and see if you get the same bug. Consider that this is not the final version and the Android Team said there are some things that they still have to fix.

Comment: I am using the v7 RecyclerView

Comment: Having the same probleme. I come back. If I find why

Comment: After some tests, I think in my case, it's not a RecyclerView problem but SwipeRefreshLayout. Stay tuned

Comment: No swiperefreshlayout in my case

Comment: Edit : Same without SwipeRefreshLayout. So I dont now why. Maybe ListView ? because there is a ListView in RecyclerView and I have repplaced my swipeRefreshLayout and my RecyclerView by a ListView

Comment: make an instance from your layoutmanager and change your code to : LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
  llm.setAutoMeasureEnabled(false);       
  mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=scrollbar&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=78545), this bug has been fixed in the new version of the support library v21.0.2.

Answer (score 3):

For me the issue was occurring because my list item views height was set to wrap_content. Changing it to match_parent fixed it for me.